# vcpkg doesn't work if I try a different clang version?

Tags: vcpkg

I'm building a C++ program on macOS. I want to try clang from the [clang website](https://clang.llvm.org), rather than the default that comes with Xcode from Apple. I downloaded a binary build of clang+llvm, unpacked it and added this line to my root `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /MyStuff/clang+llvm-15.0.1-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/clang++)
```

Now I get errors from CMake:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "range-v3" with any
  of the following names:

    range-v3Config.cmake
    range-v3-config.cmake
```

That `range-v3` is a package for a C++ library that I had installed with [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html).

Do I need to somehow update `vcpkg` to use the newer clang? How?

Here's my cmake command line:

```
cmake -B build-debug -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/rob/Dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

**Update**

I started using manifest mode. Here is my vcpkg.json

```
{
  "name": "memogu",
  "version-string": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "fmt",
    "range-v3",
    "stduuid",
    "date"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It should work but your post doesn't give enough information about what is happening. Did you clean/delete the cache? 
Try running with --trace to see if vcpkg is actually doing its stuff. 
Also do you use vcpkg in manifest or classic mode? From the description I would assume classic mode.

Comment: I'm new to this, so I just read about manifest vs classic and changed to manifest mode, by putting a vcpkg.json file in the project root. By "cache", do you mean the CMake build directory? Yes, I delete it completely and start fresh. If there is another cache, I don't know about it so maybe that's it.

Comment: Yikes, I just realized the `cmake` command is going into a loop. I get that range-v3 error, when the output starts to repeat itself. So something about setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER in my CMakeLists.txt files causes cmake to run in a loop.

Comment: where do you set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER? before or after project() ? Better provide it via the cmd line. This is a setting which belongs into a toolchain itself.

Comment: I was setting it after `project()`. Putting in on the command line works! I haven't tried putting it before `project()`; maybe that works too. I'm not sure how to put it in a toolchain file since vcpkg docs tell me to use their file for that. Both vcpkg and conan are taking over the toolchain file, which doesn't seem right. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` after `project()` makes CMake detect that the compiler changed and a reconfigure is necessary after it already ran detection. Since you didn't use a cache value it always sees a change in that variable which sends it into a loop. Doing it before `project` should also work. About the toolchain: vcpkg is fine being just included by another toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` needs to be set before `project()` or `enable_language()` since it runs compiler detection at that point. If it is set afterwards CMake will detect that change and try to reconfigure the project. If it is done without a cache variable you'll end up with an infinite reconfigure loop.
`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` should either be set via the cmd line or via a cmake toolchain file.

To provide a toolchain with vcpkg you can either use `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` or provide your toolchain as `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and just `include(vcpkg.cmake)` in your toolchain or in the `CMakeLists.txt` before `project()`